# Is it possible to cross the border at Wagah with a private car?

Tags: indian-citizens, india, borders, pakistan, wagah

I'm an Indian citizen planning to travel from Jeddah (Saudi Arabia) to Calicut (India) by car. I want to know whether I can cross the border at [Wagah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagah) with my car.